# Kotlin android retrieving Application from Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver

Is there any way to get Application object from within a BroadcastReceiver? Right now I have something like this:

```
class SmsReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    private var smsHandler = SmsHandler()

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent) {
        for (smsMessage in Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent)) {
            val application = getApplication() //This one does not work
            if (context != null) smsHandler.processSmSMessage(smsMessage, context, application)                
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `applicationObject` from `applicationContext`.

Something like this:

```
class SmsReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    private var smsHandler = SmsHandler()

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent) {
        for (smsMessage in Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent)) {
            val application = (context?.applicationContext as MyApp) ?: return
            if (context != null) smsHandler.processSmSMessage(smsMessage, context, application)                
        }
    }
}
```

Note: `MyApp` is a class that extends with `Application`